# ActionCable/Websocket: Is it possible to make a client subscribe to a channel explicitly during connection establishment from server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I have a websocket server hosted at http://localhost:3000/test when a client connects with the websocket server i want to make the client subscribe to a channel explicitly at server side without any further communication from client side.  is it possible to do this ?.

I understand that websocket server can communicate to the client to subscribe to the respective channel explicitly and then based on client logic subscription to the channel can be initiated from client side.

But is my requirement is to explicitly subscribe a client to a channel during successful connection.

I'm using the following rails/action cable version
actioncable (6.1.5)
rails (6.1.5)